# MySQL: Query to get the count of each table in a DB?

Tags: mysql, count

How could I get the count of rows from each table in a certain DB including the tables name? I know how to get the table count and the sum of rows for all tables, but not how to get the count for each table separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS, TABLE_NAME
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the tables are inside a single database, let's assume it to be "**test123**", then you can use the following command to fetch number of rows:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS 
FROM `test123`;
```

It'll return result containing the following values:

```
`Name`, `Engine`, `Version`, 
`Row_format`, `Rows`, `Avg_row_length`, 
`Data_length`, `Max_data_length`, `Index_length`, 
`Data_free`, `Auto_increment`, `Create_time`, 
`Update_time`, `Check_time`, `Collation`, 
`Checksum`, `Create_options`, `Comment`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query resolve your problem:

SELECT ‘table1’, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) AS CountTable1, 
       ‘table2’, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2) AS CountTable2